# Tablet boot in recovery mode always

Tags: recovery-mode

I have flashed TWRP Recovery and after getting in recovery mode my tablet only boot in recovery mode all time

I'm pressing powerkey only but tablet boots in recovery mode only help please :(

I have proscan plt4315-pl tablet and installed TWRP recovery from this tutorial

http://www.techknow.me/forum/index.php?topic=7389.0

Comment: More information is needed. What's the make and model number of your tablet? How did you install TWRP? Post link to instructions if you have it. Was the tablet stock, or was it already running custom ROM and recovery?

Comment: @Chahk:Updated my question and tablet running stock rom and recovery